# php soap client returns 404, when calling WSDL methods from HTTPS environment

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soap-client

I am running a php soap client example under **https** environment of my Zend Server.

I am able to list the methods in the [**WSDL**](http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL). But when i make a call to one of those methods, i receive a **404 HTTP not found** error. I also tried saving the WSDL to my local folder.

Interestingly, the same example was running successfully from the CLI (like: **C:/> php abc.php**). Not sure why it is failing in the browser (like: **https://example.com:10022/abc.php**).

This is my code:

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

try {        
       $client = new SoapClient('country.wsdl');            
       //$client = new SoapClient('http://www.webservicex.net/country.asmx?WSDL');
       //$functions = $client->__getFunctions (); var_dump ($functions); // works

            $params = array('CountryName'=> 'Australia');
            $result = $client->GetISOCountryCodeByCountyName($params);
            echo $result->GetISOCountryCodeByCountyNameResult;
    } 
    catch(SoapFault $fault) {
        echo $fault->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

**Note**:

1. I have openssl enabled.
2. My https url is configured as a Zend server Virtual Host, running on port 10022.
3. My https url is not reachable from outside world (does this make any difference?)